# Regex Phone Number in Safari using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, mobile-safari

I am using jquery/javascript to add phone number links to a table that have phone numbers. Phone numbers are in this format 222-222-1234 or 222-111-1111 (local ext is: 11111) in the HTML.  I do not have access to modify the source code.

Html code:

```
    <td>222-222-1234<td>
    <td>222-111-1111 (local ext is: 1111)</td>
```

With my code, I am trying to get this:

```
    <td><a href="tel:222-222-1234">222-222-1234</a><td>
    <td>
       <a href="tel:222-111-1111">222-111-1111</a>(local ext is: 1111)
    </td>
```

Here is my code:

```
var regex = /\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/;
$('#Listing table tr td:nth-child(3), #ListingTable tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    text = text.trim();
    text = text.replace(regex, '<a href=\"tel:$&\">$&</a>');
    $(this).html(text);
});
```

This looks like it is working in Chrome/Firefox/IE, but on my Safari on Ipad, the phone number are showing up as 222-222-1234"> with the "> at the end. I don't know if this is a problem on Safari on Ios since I don't have a Mac.

How can I get rid of the "> at the end on Safari?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for this. You can use the `html()` method. Provide it a function which accepts the current HTML string as an argument. This will contain the current phone number value, which you can wrap in the `<a>` element and return to be set as the new value. Try this:

```js
$('#Listing table tr td:nth-child(3)').html((i, h) => `<a href="tel:${h}">${h}</a>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Listing">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Ipsum</td>
      <td>222-222-1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>222-987-6543</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```